# Can I extract all matches with functions like aregexec?

Tags: r, string, mining

I've been enjoying the powerful function aregexec that allows me to mine strings in a fuzzy way.

For that I can search for a string of nucleotide "ATGGCTTCGTC" within a DNA section with defined allowance of insertion, deletion and substitute.

However, it only show me the first match without finishing the whole string. For example,

If I run

```
aregexec("a","adfasdfasdfaa")
```

only the first "a" will show up from the result. I'd like to see all the matches.

I wonder if there are other more powerful functions or a argument to be added to this one.

Thank you very much.

P.S. I explained the fuzzy search poorly. I mean, the match doesn't have to be perfect. Say if I allow an substitution of one character, and search AATTGG in  ctagtactaAATGGGatctgct, the capital part will be considered a match. I can similarly allow insertions and deletions of certain characters.

Answer (score 1):

`gregexpr` will show every time there is the pattern in the string, like in this example.

```
gregexpr("as","adfasdfasdfaa")
```

There are many more information if you use `?grep` in R, it will explain every aspect of using regex.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer. The problem with grepexpr is that I can't figure out how to use fuzzy search. For aregexec, an argument max=list(sub=1,del=2,insert=3) allows flexible search.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by fuzzy search...what do you want to mine exactly ?

Comment: I see. I will edit the question. By fuzzy search I mean the match doesn't have to be perfect. Say if I allow an substitution of one character, and search AATTGG in  ctagtactaAATGGGatctgct, the capital part will be considered a match.

Comment: Okay so maybe you need to design specifix regex? For example, this command wil match either AATTGG or AATGGG : `regexpr('AAT(T|G)GG','CTAGTACTAAATGGGATCTGCT')`. Do you have priors or regular sequences to match, not depending on what's between them?

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for you help. Unfortunately, the biology is not that simple. I'd like to search, say 20 character within a DNA string of 2000. Among the 20, each character can be substituted with the other 3 nucleic acids, and in general I can tolerate 1-2 substitutions. I have a slow fix for the aregexec where I delete the match I found and run again. I wonder how do I suggest to the author of the aregexec function.

Comment: Well I'm a biologist in evolution too so I get the point about the difficulty ^^ Your case seems difficult to code with regex (when I think about it right now). Also this function is in the core or `R`, so I doubt you can change it, because many functions/package could depend on it....Don't you have regular pattern in your sequence ? Because 20 character with all 4 basis have `1.099512e+12` combinaisons possible....

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and patience. I would try out my labor-intensive method. Also, I wonder if there are any ways to notify the authors of R language and/or aregexec, to make a function like aregexec2.